# AWS - Lambda function not waiting for async/await axios call

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await, gupshup

I have a lambda function in which I am making an axios call to a third party API. I have put my post request in try/catch and also using async await but nothing is getting printed in cloudwatch logs. The lambda function is not timeouting, I have even set my lambda timeout time to 15 minutes. It seems like the axios call is never invoking. Below is my code:

```
exports.saveWebhooks = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const data = req.body
        let insertData = {
            insertedAt: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
            data: data,
            status: 0
        }
        await db.collection('gupshup_interactive_webhooks').insertOne(insertData);
        res.status(200).send('');
        console.log('inserted');
        const payload = data.payload;
        const userMessage = payload.payload.text;
        if (data.type == 'message') {
            if (userMessage == 'hey' || userMessage == 'Hey') {
                console.log("in hey");
            } else {
                // console.log("in else");
                const param = {
                    message: '{"type":"text","text":"Sorry, I didn\'t get you. Type \"Hey\" to start!"}',
                    channel: `your text`'whatsapp',
                    source: 91xxxxxxxxx,
                    'src.name': 'Demo',
                    destination: 91xxxxxxxxx
                };
                const config = {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'https://third_party_api',
                    headers: {
                        'accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'apikey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
                    },
                    data: param
                };
                try {
                    console.log(config)
                    const response = await axios(config);
                    console.log(response.data);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err.message)
                    console.log(err.response.data)
                }
                console.log("after axios call")
            }
        } else {
            // Handle other cases if needed
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

In my above code saveWebhooks is my endpoint in which I have attached API Gateway. The code is running fine and all console.logs are getting printed even the console that says after axios call is also getting printed but nothing is printed inside try/catch for axios call.

Also, the code is running fine in local. The third party API which I am using is to send a whatsapp message using gupshup API's. My lambda function is not running in VPC and I have also given the AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole permission to my role so that lambda can access the internet.

Can anybody please help on what I might be missing in my code?

Comment: Did you try to call without await, which means synchronous call and see what is happening?

Comment: yes i did it did not worked, the lambda function was ending before my axios call

Comment: Is the issue still exists, can you let me know what error lambda is throwing? What made the lambda stop before axios statement?

Answer (score 0):

The below line will send the response and exit the middleware/code.

```
res.status(200).send('');
```